# Не получается добавить Tomcat в Intellij

Tags: tomcat

У меня премиум версия idea,качала Tomcat с офф сайта,перепробывала все версии  - не опознает.В чем же может быть проблема,подскажите
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы скачали `zip` из раздела `Source Code Distributions` - это видно по "src" на вашей картинке.
Скачайте из раздела `Binary Distributions`:
[apache-tomcat-10.0.27-windows-x64.zip](https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.27/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.27-windows-x64.zip)

Распакуйте и укажите в IDE пути до распакованной директории.

Comment: Да,действительно.Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в Tomcat base directory в конце пути дописать \bin